# Select View dynamically in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

may anyone please share your expertise .

i have a table contain customerid and it has only 1 specific value at a given time.

DDL Table:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER
 (

   [CUSTOMERID] [int] NOT NULL
     )

 INSERT     CUSTOMER

 SELECT 100 UNION
 SELECT 105 UNION
 SELECT 108
```

here in example i have showed 3 value, **but** in table there will be always 1 value  **at given  time**.
**and before loading other value, first value will get deleted.**

now i have 60 views created for 60 different customer. each customer has different data pattern and logic associated with it.

example of views. Note: This is just example and not actual logic

```
CREATE VIEW V1
as
(
select * from dwhtable
where colummnx = '100'
)

similarly 

CREATE VIEW V2
as
(
select * from dwhtable
where columnx = '105
)
```

Mapping Table

```
create table mapping_table
(
custID int,
view_name varchar (150)
)

insert mapping_table

select 100, 'v1' union all
select 105, 'v2' union all
select 108, 'v3'
```

i am trying to automate the entire process either by SP or Function or DynamicSQL.

So my views will run for a specific customer.
Now  How do we know which view goes with which customer.

The customer table will come in picture, and we need to match the value in customer table and which view contain that value.

i am not sure whether it is achievable in sql.
Please share your expertise.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to have so many views? Is it a requirement? You can create a table function or SP with input parameter @customer_id. That function (or SP) will return only the data for one customer.

Comment: I agree with Anton. You dont need to create anything since you have a table which can be filtered by customerId field

Comment: @Anton: yes u are right.... but its a requirement. i have to manipulate data as per individual requirement. Please help

Comment: so you need a mapping table to map each customer to the name of view. Then you can use EXEC or sp_execute_sql to execute dynamic SQL

Comment: may anyone Please help me without change the scenario.

Comment: @anton: Thanks a lot ... it would be great if you can provide sample code

Comment: Do you have a separate mapping table or view name is in CUSTOMER table?

Comment: this does not make sense. Why would you want to hard code a view for a specific customer ? How would your application handle that ?

Comment: you want to create view for each customer right?? What is 100,105,and 108 in your select query

Comment: @Anton: i have created a mapping table

Comment: @Squirrel: Please suggest if some better way to handle it.

Comment: Don't really understand your requirement here . Maybe you can explain the big picture what are you trying to achive . . Why do you need to create 1 VIEW per CUSTOMER ?

Comment: @Squirrel: after implementing  SCD-2, i have to move data with some modification to datamart table, from where we can have some report and do subscription. now the reason for multiple view is the modification requested by each customer is different. The challenge here is how to call the specific view, so i thought to match the customerID mention in the view and available in the customer table which i shows at the begining of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand the task correctly. So the requirement is to have one view per customer. We need to get all the columns from that view for a given customer.

So you need to have a mapping table Customer_View_Mapping (customer_id int, view_name varchar(128))

Then you can get the name of view:

```
declare @name varchar(128)
select @name = view_name from Customer_View_Mapping where customer_id = @customer_id
```

the you can execute something like this:

```
EXEC (N'select * from ' + @name)
```

You can insert the results to the temp table if required.

```
INSERT INTO #table (<column list>)
EXEC (N'select * from ' + @name)
```

Comment: Thanks i will mark it as answer, allow me to do some testing

Comment: getting error like Must declare the scalar variable "@name".

Comment: getting error like Must declare the scalar variable "@name". and Incorrect syntax near 'from' please help

Comment: That was just a draft. I updated the answer to include a declaration of variable.

Comment: which one? first or second? check the mapping table name and view name are correct. In my post, I use Customer_View_Mapping, you use mapping_table

Comment: Anton: i think second

Comment: then add "PRINT @name" to see what is the value of "@name". I have to go, I'll check it tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks Anton. we will meet tomorrow